# Calculation position of a Vector between two others

Tags: java, math, libgdx

I think my current problem is related to intercept theorems that everybody learned at school, but that was quite some time ago and I am kind of getting stuck halfway.

### My Problem:

I have two Vectors in a 2 dimensional space called `v1` and `v2`.
What I want to know are the coordinates of a vector `v3` which is on the line segement between `v1` and `v2`.
What I know about v3 is the length of the line segement between `v1` and `v3` and `v2` and `v3`.
I my thoughs are always circling about the using the slope between `v1` and `v2` to determine the coordinates of `v3` but at this point I'm getting stuck.

This the actual code I used for the issue:

```
private Vector2 getPointOnLine(Vector2 v1, Vector2 v2, float distance) throws Exception
{
    double lengthOfSegment=Math.floor(Math.pow(v2.x - v1.x, 2)+Math.pow(v2.y-v1.y,2));

    Vector2 slopeXY=v2.sub(v1);
    float slope=1/slopeXY.x;
    slopeXY.x=slopeXY.x*slope;
    slopeXY.y=slopeXY.y*slope;
}
```

The actuell problem is game related, I want to let an allied unit (v2) follow the player(v1), but always keep a specific distance (distance).

I'm using LibGDX, are there by chance any library functions that can do this work for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to interpolate and get a vector which is a 'mix' of v1 and v2. This will be on the line between them. (Assuming v1 and v2 are treated as position vectors)
You can do this by taking a weighted average of the vectors, but if the distance is given in absolute terms rather than relative, then you will need to convert:

Actually, it turns out libGDX vectors can do this for you!:

```
private Vector2 getPointOnLine(Vector2 v1, Vector2 v2, float distance) 
{
    double length = Math.hypot(v1.x - v2.x, v1.y - v2.y);
    distance /= length;
    return v1.cpy().lerp(v2, distance);

}
```

Vector2.lerp is a linear interpolation method provided by libGDX

Comment: thanks, i think i need to expirment a little with it, cause everytime the returned vector is the same as v1.

Comment: @Aeglasin I think this is because libGDX vectors are mutable, meaning this code actually changes v1 to the result! I will change it to perform a copy, avoiding this. If you actually would like to set one of the positions of your objects to the new, interpolated position, you can remove the copy and use the lerp() method from the vector to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the ratio of the distances `d(v1,v3)` and `d(v1,v2) = d(v1,v3) + d(v3,v2)`. Let

```
r = d(v1,v3)/(d(v1,v3) + d(v3,v2))
```

Then

```
v3 = v1 + r(v2-v1)
```

is the answer to your question.

Proof: If `d(v1,v3)=0`, `r=0` and `v3=v1`. If `d(v3,v2)=0` then `r=1` and `v3 = v1+v2-v1 = v2`. The formula for `v3` is linear, and it passes through both `v1` and `v2`, so `v3` is always on the line between those vectors. Finally, `norm(v3-v1) = r * norm(v2-v1) = d(v1,v3)` and a similar calculation for `norm(v2-v3)`.